# Как удалить /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html и создать вместо него index.html

Tags: nginx, debian

Как удалить /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html и создать вместо него index.html

Comment: А зачем? Просто перенастройте root на вашу собственную папку с вашими файлами да и всё, не?

Comment: Могу предложить вам перейти в необходимую папку и просто переименовать файл : mv index.nginx-debian.html index.html

Comment: Потребуются права владельца директории либо root

Comment: чего вы хотите добиться этим?